# Como desabilitar todos os TextView de uma Atividade?

Tags: android, android-layout

Há algum método que desabilite todos os controles de uma determinada atividade no android?

Comment: Herik, não existe nenhum método que faça isso de forma automática. Pode fazer manualmente, ou se quer algo genérico, sugiro percorrer os elementos da sua `View` e desabilitar os elementos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe um método na `Activity` que faça isso de forma automática. A única forma, genérica (sem ter que desabilitar elemento a elemento manualmente), seria iterar sobre todos os elementos do layout e desabilitar um a um.

Fiz um método que faz isso:

```
void setEnabledForAll(View root, boolean enabled) {
    // Desabilito a própria View
    root.setEnabled(enabled);

    // Se ele for um ViewGroup, isso é, comporta outras Views.
    if(root instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) root;

        // Percorro os filhos e desabilito de forma recursiva
        for(int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); ++i) {
            setEnabledForAll(group.getChildAt(i), enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

Para usar o método basta chamá-lo passando a `View` raiz de sua `Activity` ou qualquer "ramo" da árvore que queria de começar a desabilitar. Por exemplo:

```
// Usando a raiz da Activity
View raizActivity = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
setEnabledForAll(raizActivity, false);
```

Comment: Seu algoritmo atendeu perfeitamente a minha necessidade.